# Spring MVC and the @Data annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

- I am using `SpringToolSuite` as IDE and developing using `Spring MVC`.
- In the model part of my application I am defining a bean called *Ingredient*

```java
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Ingredient {
    
    public Ingredient(String string, String string2, Type wrap) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Type type;
    public enum Type{
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }

}
```

- As I am using the *`@Data`* annotation from **Lombok** I can suppose that a constructor taking the 3 attributes is automatically created as well as getter and setters.
- But as in the controller I call  *`new Ingredient("FLTO", "Flour Tortilla", Type.WRAP)`* I get a redline under the instruction with a message that tells me that there is no constructor with the parameters in question.

  - I don't understand because the class Ingredient is marked with the Lombok's annotation *`@Data`*
- The errors cause the running of the SpringBoot's project to crash

```sh
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    The method asList(T...) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments (Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient, Ingredient)
    The constructor Ingredient(String, String, Ingredient.Type) is undefined
.........................
```

Comment: It won't generate a constructor with all arguments by default. You need to add `@AllArgsConstructor` for that. So your understanding is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Data` documentation

```
Equivalent to @Getter @Setter @RequiredArgsConstructor @ToString @EqualsAndHashCode.
```

As your fields are not marked as `final` they are not covered by the `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

Therefor

1. Declare the required fields as `final` or
2. Use `@AllArgsConstructor`

Edit

```
@Data
public class Ingredient {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;
    public enum Type{
        WRAP, PROTEIN, VEGGIES, CHEESE, SAUCE
    }

}
```

gets delomoked to:

```
@Data
public class Ingredient {
    private final String id;
    private final String name;
    private final Type type;

    @java.beans.ConstructorProperties({"id", "name", "type"})
    public Ingredient(String id, String name, Type type) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }
....
}
```

And then I can use

```
 Ingredient test = new Ingredient("id", "name", Ingredient.Type.CHEESE);
```

Comment: I marked the Ingredient's fields as final. SpringToolWebsuite marks them as error because they seem uninitialized. In the controller the Ingredient's contructor with the parameters is still in error! It seems the annotation @Data il not processed

Comment: I've updated my post - lombok generates the corresponding constructor with `@Data` and `final` fields

Answer (score 0):

`@Data` annotation creates constructor for annotation `@RequiredArgsConstructor`

`@RequiredArgsConstructor` creates constructor for uninitialized final fields or fields annotated with `@NonNull`. Your fields are not `final` nor `@NonNull` hence constructor `Ingredient(String, String, Ingredient.Type)` is not generated

If you want generate all args constructor I would add `@AllArgsConstructor` annotation or you have to satisfy conditions mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code in the IDE and there no error.

Make sure in your IDE you have annotation processing enabled. Also if you are using Gradle make sure you have the `annotationProcessor` for `lombok` in the right place.

The constructor is not automatically created by using data. Using `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will generate a constructor based on the required fields (`final` fields).

Comment: I am new to Spring Tools Suite. Where do I check that the annotations are processed?
 am using maven and the Lombok is in the dependencies

Comment: The command mvn package print *build success*. It looks like a problem with STS.

Comment: I had to add lombok to the Eclipse plugins list like [explained on that link](https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working through the "Spring in action book", from @Craig Walls.
Anyway, I had the same issue. I'm actually working on it in the moment.

Nothing helped until I've read exactly what @Craig Walls says in the book:

> Why are there so many errors in my code? It bears repeating that when
> using Lombok, you must install the Lombok plugin into your IDE.
> Without it, your IDE won’t be aware that Lombok is providing getters,
> setters, and other methods and will complain that they are missing.
> Lombok is supported in a number of popular IDEs, including Eclipse,
> Spring Tool Suite, IntelliJ IDEA, and Visual Studio Code. Visit
> https://projectlombok .org/ for more information on how to install the
> Lombok plugin into your IDE.

I could say so much as it helped me to

- download the jar file from https://projectlombok.org/
- start the jar file from the command line (admin rights!!!)
- restart STS (or any other IDE you working with)

and afterwards

- validate project in STS (right klick in the package explorer)
- update maven project. (right klick in the package explorer)

Basically as it is written [here](https://medium.com/@alisnagina/how-to-install-lombok-in-sts-eclipse-on-window-10-2e2169b41636):

After that all errors have disappeared.

I hope I could help!